# Override standard request processing for min and max price in WooCommerce filter to get products by price from custom field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filter

The price of the item is recorded in the custom field $ custom_price of the table in the database, which has the item ID and price. Accordingly, when filtering by price on the category page, it filters only by the standard WooCommerce price field.  I need to filter products in category by min and max price by custom price field, what is in custom table wp_product_prices. For example: I filtered products by price using woocommerce filter and got results on category page. The probem is: products don't showing because I using not standard field for price in my products https://prnt.sc/w60uj8 Found only the file https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-query.php, it has request processing by price, function price_filter_post_clauses ($ args, $ wp_query).  Maybe there is some kind of hook for overriding or how you can implement it?
My custom prices table  to products https://prnt.sc/w60t5p The field "product_id" is equal to product "ID" in wp_posts table.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I can't say I understand what you're asking at all. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for  attention. I need to filter products in category by min and max price by custom price field, what is in custom  table wp_product_prices. For example: I filtered products by price using woocommerce filter and got results on category page. The probem  is: products don't showing because I using not standard field for price in my products.

Answer (score 4):

for change query for min & max price use action "woocommerce_product_query" and deactivate standard filter 'posts_clauses'. Like this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'min_max_price_handler');

function min_max_price_handler($q) {
    global $wpdb, $wp_query;

    if (! $wp_query->is_main_query() || ( ! isset($_GET['max_price']) && ! isset($_GET['min_price']))) {
        return;
    }

    // Remove default Woocommerce min/max price request handler
    remove_filter('posts_clauses', [WC()->query, 'price_filter_post_clauses'], 10);

    $current_min_price = isset($_GET['min_price']) ? floatval(wp_unslash($_GET['min_price'])) : 0;
    $current_max_price = isset($_GET['max_price']) ? floatval(wp_unslash($_GET['max_price'])) : PHP_INT_MAX;

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM wp_product_prices WHERE country=%s AND price >= %f AND price <= %f";

    $results = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            $sql,
            $customer_country,
            $current_min_price,
            $current_max_price
        ),
        ARRAY_A
    );

    $results = array_column($results, 'product_id');

    if (is_array($results)) {
        $q->set('post__in', $results);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but want to more organic solution with minimum modify. Can I change function woocommerce/includes/class-wc-query.php > price_filter_post_clauses() by filter?

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It helped me. :) For anyone who might be looking to use it on the category pages, use "product_query_post_clauses" instead of "price_filter_post_clauses" as the filter to remove.